# Determine material feed speed in a sawing solution for a lumbermill

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I work in a lumbermill.  I'm working on an excel spreadsheet that supplies a lot of information about our sawing operation, not least of which is the horsepower requirement for one of our saws.  The following equation can be used to find the HP requirement for the motor driving the saw arbor:

$$HP = \frac{c\cdot d\cdot x\cdot y\cdot z}{144}$$

If you are interested, the values represented here are:

- c = The material feed speed.
- d = The number of saws in the cut.
- x = The depth of cut.
- y = The combined kerf of all saws divided by the number of saws in the cut.
- z = The wood density factor.

For example, the following is the same equation solved using some of my data:

$$406.5 = \frac{467\cdot7\cdot3.8\cdot0.124\cdot38}{144}$$

What I would like to do is come up with an equation that will allow me to determine the material feed speed that would give me a 300HP solution.

Essentially, I need a way to solve for c in the following equation, keeping in mind that the other values, represented by d, x, y, and z in the above formula will be fed into the equation and could be different numbers altogether.

$$300 = \frac{c\cdot7\cdot3.8\cdot0.124\cdot38}{144}$$

This might seem simple to a lot of people here, but it has been a long, long time since I had high school algebra classes.  Once I get this solved, I'll be moving on to determine the feed speed required to keep saw gullet fill percentages at an acceptable level.

Comment: Essentially what I am trying to do is have my spreadsheet display a recommended feed speed in order to keep the HP requirement at 300 or below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply by $144$ and divide by $dxyz$ to get
$$c=\frac {300\cdot 144}{dxyz}$$

Comment: ... and that gives you the *maximum* feed rate.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you so much.  This is the first time I have used this service, is there a method to mark my question as answered or to mark your answer as correct?